# Install R package fgsea: Error in download.file

Tags: r, package, bioconductor

I want to install R package. Every time it comes out:

`> Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...)`

I have no idea of that, any suggestion?

```
> BiocManager::install("fgsea")
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cloud.r-project.org

Bioconductor version 3.6 (BiocManager 1.30.15), R 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Installing package(s) 'BiocVersion', 'fgsea'
also installing the dependencies ‘formatR’, ‘lambda.r’, ‘futile.options’, ‘futile.logger’, ‘snow’, ‘BiocParallel’

Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) 


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=zh_CN.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

It is very difficult to open stack overflow in my country. I tried to provide the correct answer in the command, but I can not open it.

So the correct answer is :

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

change "focal" which is corresponding to Ubuntu 20.04.1

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Crossposted at https://www.biostars.org/p/9475002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the correct answer is :

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

change "focal" which is corresponding to Ubuntu 20.04.1

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`